# Cannot resolve method 'getData()'

Tags: java, android

I follow this quide at http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android
i have to make a app with a gallery inbuilt.
i wanted to customize it so i did this and now its showing this error

```
package com.example.hakdows.anandraoadsul;

import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.GridView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Gallery extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAdapter gridAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter( this,R.layout.grid_item_layout.getData());
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gallery, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

this is my gallery class file

please help. It says Cannot resolve method 'getData()'

sorry if it was a silly question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to you Galler Activity, you forgot to add method.
I copy that from where you shared a tutorial link

```
// Prepare some dummy data for gridview
    private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
        final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
        TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
            imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
        }
        return imageItems;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there should be comma instead of dot:

```
this,R.layout.grid_item_layout , getData()
```

Second, you should have method `getData()` in your `Gallery` class, which will provide you with data for adapter.

Answer (score -2):

Import Array list in GridViewAdapter.java class